# How do i formulate "if this.children.has.not.class" in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have a list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Whatnot</a></li>
   <li class="left-main-list active"><a href="#">Whatnot1</a></li>
      <ul class="random">
         <li><a href="#">BK Sang, Oxelesund</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Boxholms BS</a></li>
      </ul>
   <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Whatnot2</a></li>
</ul>
```

First of all i wonder, is the second `<ul class="random">`a child of the list item above?

If so, i would like to make an if statement, saying that if one would click an item with a class of `"left-main-list"` i want to see if their child has a class at all, and if it hasn't, i want to add a class ("random") to that child.

If this in fact is not a child, i would want a way of checking if that second ul has a class at all, and if not, add "random" to that ul. I'm guessing i will have to give it an id if it's not a child of the list item above?

Any help will be appreciated! 
/Bill

Comment: There is no class=random in your code.

Comment: Now it is, but actually, i wanted to see if it's children has a class at all, and if not, add one..  :)

Comment: To answer one of your questions the ul with class="random" is NOT a child of the li.  It is a child of the first ul.

Comment: You can use $('ul').hasClass('.classname') to test an element.

Comment: You've invalid HTML, `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` elements.

Comment: @DavidThomas No, the first `ul` contains the second `ul` as a child.

Comment: The UL above can't contain another UL

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm talking about this `<li class="left-main-list active"><a href="#">Whatnot1</a></li>
      <ul class="random">...`

Comment: @Kolink: yeah, I just caught that (after staring at it for thirty seconds). Gosh, it's getting late... (other comment deleted, for reasons of blindness and/or stupidity).

Comment: The immediate children of `<ul>` elements must be `<li>`. However, you are always free to nest any element in the `<li>` elements, including another `<ul>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid UL cannot contain another UL. This will add class `random`to the children of li.left-main-list which doesn't have any class at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/MERF5/

```
<ul>
   <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Whatnot</a></li>
   <li class="left-main-list active"><a href="#">Whatnot1</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">BK Sang, Oxelesund</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Boxholms BS</a></li>
      </ul>
       </li>
   <li class="left-main-list"><a href="#">Whatnot2</a></li>
</ul>


$('.left-main-list').click(function(){
    $(this).children(':not([class])').addClass('random')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that rour HTML is invalid and the second `ul` should be inside an `li` element.

Also, you do not have to check if the `element` has a specific class before adding that class. jQuery will not add duplicate classes if the element already has the specified class.

However, here's how you could find `ul` elements without the `.random` class under an `li` (*I assumed `this` was the `li`*):

```
$(this).children('ul:not(.random)');
```